# To check if a value exists in one column, and generate results accordinly in another column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the Customer_id and Status columns, and I am trying to generate `"Final_Status"` column for a large dataset on Python using Pandas.

Example :

| Customer_ID | Status | Final_Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Rejected | Rejected |
| 1 | Rejected | Rejected |
| 1 | Rejected | Rejected |
| 2 | Success | Success |
| 2 | Success | Success |
| 3 | Rejected | Rejected |
| 3 | Rejected | Rejected |
| 3 | Success | Rejected |

In this data, a customer can appear multiple times and if a customer gets rejected at least once, then he should be rejected at all the occurrences as shown in `"Final_Status"` column for `Customer_Id` `3`.

I tried some built in functions like `shift` on pandas, but cases like Customer ID `2` were also getting `"Rejected"` under `Final_Status` column.

Answer (score 2):

You can use :

```
# does the customer got rejected at least once ?
m = df["Status"].eq("Rejected").groupby(df["Customer_ID"]).transform("any")

df["Final_Status"] = np.where(m, "Rejected", "Success")
```

Output :

```
print(df) # with intermediate `m`

   Customer_ID    Status Final_Status     #       m 
0            1  Rejected     Rejected     #    True
1            1  Rejected     Rejected     #    True
2            1  Rejected     Rejected     #    True
3            2   Success      Success     #   False
4            2   Success      Success     #   False
5            3  Rejected     Rejected     #    True
6            3  Rejected     Rejected     #    True
7            3   Success     Rejected     #    True
```

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot!